# Automation Studio Data Views - typos or something else in the column names in Salesforce documentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-views

I'm checking new Data Views *_AutomationInstance* and *_AutomationActivityInstance*. In the first of them I found a typo in Salesforce documentation. On the page we can see *AutomationNotificationRecipient_Compete*, but this column name is *AutomationNotificationRecipient_Complete*.

But I see also an error in *_AutomationActivityInstance*. Query Studio tells me that (pretty important) column *ActivityInstanceErrorDetails* does not exist in this Data View. I tried to find a typo, but wasn't able. Did some of you alredy played with this?

This is the query, which I'm using:

```
SELECT
    MemberID,
    AutomationName,
    AutomationCustomerKey,
    AutomationInstanceID,
    ActivityType,
    CASE
        WHEN ActivityType = 33 THEN 'SMS Activity'
        WHEN ActivityType = 42 THEN 'Send Email'
        WHEN ActivityType = 43 THEN 'Import File'
        WHEN ActivityType = 45 THEN 'Refresh Group'
        WHEN ActivityType = 53 THEN 'File Transfer'
        WHEN ActivityType = 73 THEN 'Data Extract'
        WHEN ActivityType = 84 THEN 'Report Definition'
        WHEN ActivityType = 300 THEN 'SQL Query'
        WHEN ActivityType = 303 THEN 'Filter'
        WHEN ActivityType = 423 THEN 'Script'
        WHEN ActivityType = 425 THEN 'Data Factory Utility Activity'
        WHEN ActivityType = 426 THEN 'Refresh Segment Template'
        WHEN ActivityType = 427 THEN 'Publish Audience'
        WHEN ActivityType = 467 THEN 'Wait'
        WHEN ActivityType = 724 THEN 'Refresh Mobile Filtered List'
        WHEN ActivityType = 725 THEN 'Send SMS'
        WHEN ActivityType = 726 THEN 'Import Mobile Contacts'
        WHEN ActivityType = 733 THEN 'Journey Builder Event Activity'
        WHEN ActivityType = 736 THEN 'Send Push'
        WHEN ActivityType = 749 THEN 'Fire Event'
        WHEN ActivityType = 771 THEN 'Salesforce Email Send'
        WHEN ActivityType = 772 THEN 'Mobile Connect Send Salesforce Sync Subscriber'
        WHEN ActivityType = 783 THEN 'Send GroupConnect'
        WHEN ActivityType = 1000 THEN 'Verification'
        WHEN ActivityType = 1010 THEN 'Interaction Studio Data'
        WHEN ActivityType = 1101 THEN 'Interactions'
        WHEN ActivityType = 1701 THEN 'Batch Personalization'
        WHEN ActivityType = 3700 THEN 'Contact to Business Unit Mapping'
    END AS ActivityTypeName,
    ActivityName,
    ActivityDescription,
    ActivityCustomerKey,
    ActivityInstanceStep,
    ActivityInstanceID,
    ActivityInstanceStartTime_UTC,
    ActivityInstanceEndTime_UTC,
    ActivityInstanceStatus,
    ActivityInstanceErrorDetails
FROM
    _AutomationActivityInstance
```

And the error is *Error saving the Query field.Invalid column name 'ActivityInstanceErrorDetails'.*
When I delete column *ActivityInstanceErrorDetails* from the query, it works correctly.

Comment: I guess the field name should be `ActivityInstanceActivityErrorDetails` instead of `ActivityInstanceErrorDetails`... you can find details here, I also wonder somtimes, community n MVPs are providing more/accurate details than SF docs :-| ... Thanks to [Mateusz Dąbrowski](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/) for [this great article](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-system-data-views/#_automationinstance)

Comment: @VishalKumarCV I'm still getting the error invalid column name even with the one you have mentioned

Comment: For me the same, *ActivityInstanceActivityErrorDetails* also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with: ActivityInstanceStatusDetails

Comment: Yeah, just found this as well - it is listed in a couple example in the docs (look at first two). Seems to be just a typo putting error instead of status.

Comment: All values I got for this column were "System Error occurred. Please contact support for details." Seems this column isn't ready yet for the data view

Comment: Yeah, there is issue with it and duplicates in the main AutomationInstance data view. Hope it will be fixed in near future.